# What I'm doing wrong with relative path? Lua require error

Tags: lua, runtime-error, require, relative-path

I have tried everything but still can not require file in Lua. I am using LuaEdit 2010 on Windows 8.1
Relative path is still not working. I used these commands, which i have found but I still get the error below. My file is C:\Lua\file.lua, but I need to use relative path.

```
package.path = package.path .. ";../?.lua"
require ("file.lua") --also require ("file")
```

My error is:

```
Runtime Error at line -1: c:\lua\diplomka4.lua:S3: module 'file' not
found:
no field package.preload['file']
no file '.\ﬁle.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaEdit 2010\lua\file.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaEdit 2010\lua\file\init.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaEdit 2010\file.lua‘
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaEdit 2010\file\init.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\file.luac'
no file '../file.lua'
no file '.\file.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaEdit 2010\file.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaEdit 2010\loadall.dll'
```

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the working directory of the program not the path of the file being run. Where are you when you run this? If you need file/module relative paths there are tricks for that in the lua-users.org wiki I believe.

Comment: seems like my problem, i need to set the current directory (where I run the script)  what is C:\Lua, or any other directory on other computers to be able to require some file.lua. In other words I need to require the file always in the directory where i run the script, but not even abolute path is working...

Comment: `require` doesn't take paths as-such. It takes "names".